# Приоритеты и последнее вхождение в регулярке

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день!

Пишу небольшое расширение для корпоративного сайта на javascript.

С сайта вытягивается оригинал письма в формате plain/text.

Требуется найти последний ip адрес **ИЛИ** ip-адрес, который идет после слова unknown, причем, если в письме встречается слово unknown то взять Ip-адрес, который идет сразу после него.

На данный момент имеется такое регулярное выражение:

/[([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3})]|.nknown.[([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3})]/gi

По этой регулярке я получаю только ПЕРВЫЙ ip-адрес. Как найти последнее вхождение в регулярке и реализовать приоритеты поиска?

Comment: Если текст достаточно большой, имеет смысл воспользоваться 3 разными регулярками. `.*` в `(?:.*unknown|.*[^\d]|^)` может вызвать таймаут при откате. Вообще, лучше не использовать альтернативы, которые находят один и тот же текст в одной и той же позиции. По крайней мере, если вы решили использовать выражение Висмана, измените блок предварительного просмотра на `(?:.*(?:unknown|\D)|^)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

До конца ваш вопрос не понятен, но предлагаю такой вариант

```
/(?:.*unknown|.*[^\d]|^)([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})/i
```

Возврат данных идет в 1 группе. Приоритет поиска задан в `(?:.*unknown|.*[^\d]|^)`, то есть сначала идет попытка найти последнее (`.*unknown`) слово `unknown` за которым сразу идет ip адрес. Если такой вариант не найден, то идет поиск последнего (`.*[^\d]`) ip адреса и поиск ip в начале строки (`^`).

Пример 1 https://regex101.com/r/EEhyIg/4

Пример 2 https://regex101.com/r/EEhyIg/5

Если нужно найти первое вхождение `unknownIP` или последний `IP`, то регулярку меняем так

```
/(?:.*?unknown|.*[^\d]|^)([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})/i
```

Пример 3 https://regex101.com/r/EEhyIg/6

Пример 4 https://regex101.com/r/EEhyIg/7

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А если Искать не в одной строке а именно в тексте? 

Т.е. такой пример https://regex101.com/r/EEhyIg/11

В данном примере регулярка находит ПЕРВЫЙ ip адрес. Как мне найти ПОСЛЕДНИЙ

Comment: @garmayev, замените все `.*` на `[\S\s]*`.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает. .* как я понял - пожирает символы без разбора, а [\S\s]?

Comment: Нашел еще один пример https://regex101.com/r/EEhyIg/12 вместо unknown найден последний ip?

Comment: @garmayev, так вы в вопросе пишете, что сразу за unknown должен идти ip, а в действительности за словом идут посторонние символы. Это надо учитывать при составлении регулярок! Например так https://regex101.com/r/EEhyIg/13